# traffic layer api for python

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, traffic

I want to call google traffic layer api from a python code. so that i have to call traffic layer api as a inline call like that, i have to get the latest traffic update snapshot. can anyone help?
i tried this, but this returns static map. I know that traffic layer api is only available for js.

1st try =

```
url = 'https://mt0.google.com/vt?x='+str(start_x+x)+'&y='+str(start_y+y)+'&z='+str(self._zoom)
```

2nd try:

```
'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=12.955232,77.579923&size=600x600&zoom=17&sensor=false&layer=t&key=[my_secret_key]
```